# How to fill a 2D through input and then read back as output in a C++. Here is the code which I wrote. I gives wrong output.I am a beginner

Tags: c++, c++11, codeblocks

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a = 1;

    if (a == 1) {
        int a[1][1];
        for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= 1; j++) {

                cin >> a[i][j];
            }
        }
        cout << endl;

        for (int k = 0; k <= 1; k++) {

            for (int l = 0; l <= 1; l++) {
                cout << a[k][l] << "   ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }


    }

    return 0;
}
```

In this program if we enter input as :
1
2
3
4

it gives output :
1  3
3  1
it should give output as:
1  2
3  4
Please help, I am a beginner.
I am coding in code blocks.

Comment: `int a[1][1];` has a single element. Its only valid index is `a[0][0]`. All your loops go out of bounds and invoke undefined behavior. Change `for(int k=0;k<1;k++)`

Comment: it is unfortunate that the same syntax is used for different things. `int a[1][1];` declares an array with 1 element, but `int x = b[1][1];` accesses the second element in the second subarray of `b`

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Actually, they should change array to 2x2: `int a[2][2];`, they want to store 4 inputs.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen right, maybe `for(int k=0; k < SIZE; k++)` would have been more clear

Comment: When declaring an array, the size is the number of elements, not the top index.

Comment: fwiw, using `std::array` (or `std::vector`) helps to avoid this and uncountable other problems

Comment: You really should invest in [some decent books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), and maybe even take a class or two?

Comment: Here, `int a[1][1];` defines only one element. You have to define as `int a[2][2];` to store 2x2 array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
int main()
{
int arr[2][2]; // declares a 2x2 array

    cout << "Enter integers : " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            cin >> arr[i][j]; //inserts at the index i and j in the array
        }
    }

    cout << "Display array : " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            cout << arr[i][j] << endl; /*displays the value at 
            index i and j in the array*/
        }
    }
}
```